# Powershell SendKeys command not sending data

Tags: powershell

I'm a novice with PowerShell. I put together what I thought would be a simple script. I'm creating a VPN autologin script utilizing the Cisco VPNCLI. I'm having an issue at the end where the values are not being sent with the command [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$value{Enter}"). I hope that I am not missing something obvious.

```
$VPNclipath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client\vpncli.exe"
$VPN = "my.vpn.com"
$group = "GroupName"
$user = "DOMAIN\$env:username"
$encpass = Get-Content C:\Temp\VPN.txt
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $encpass
$accept? = "y"


###Connnect to VPN###
Function VPNConnect()
{
Start-Process -FilePath $VPNclipath -ArgumentList "connect $VPN"
}

VPNConnect

Start-Sleep -m 2000
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$group{Enter}")
Start-Sleep -m 2000
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$user{Enter}")
Start-Sleep -m 2000
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$password{Enter}")
Start-Sleep -m 2000
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$accept?{Enter}")
Start-Sleep -m 2000
```

Comment: 1) I would be surprised if trying to send keystrokes worked at all. I would look into whether the VPN connection tool you're using supports other command-line parameters. 2) It's unlikely the VPN connection tool will accept the encrypted password you're trying to use. The password will probably need to be passed as plain-text (if the VPN tool lets you pass a password at all).

Comment: There's a Powershell module on PSGallery which adds cmdlets to do this type of thing - POSH-VPN. Even if you don't use the module you can look at the code to show how you do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running your powershell code as a script, you will need to start your script by loading the .NET Framework class that you're referencing.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
```

Comment: Been working on the script. I added the line Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms and it started sending the values.

Answer (score 0):

This is the updated script with the added line suggested by Nas. Not finished, but it does connect to the VPN. Much appreciated Nas

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$vpnclipath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco\Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility 
Client\vpncli.exe"
$VPN = "my.vpn.com"
$group = "1"
$user = "DOMAIN\$env:username"
$securepass = Import-Clixml -Path 'C:\Temp\VPN.xml'
$password = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($securepass))
$accept? = "y"



###Close all Cisco Apps###
Stop-Process -Name vpnagent.exe -Force
Stop-Process -Name vpnui.exe -Force
Start-Sleep -m 2000



###Disconnect VPN###
Function VPNDisconnect()
{
Start-Process -FilePath $vpnclipath -ArgumentList "disconnect"
}
VPNDisconnect
Start-Sleep -m 2000

###Close all Cisco Apps###
Stop-Process -Name vpnagent.exe -Force
Stop-Process -Name vpnui.exe -Force
Start-Sleep -m 2000

###Connect to VPN###
Function VPNConnect()
{
Start-Process -FilePath $vpnclipath -ArgumentList "connect $VPN"
}

VPNConnect

Start-Sleep -m 2000
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$group{Enter}")
Start-Sleep -m 2000
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$user{Enter}")
Start-Sleep -m 2000
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$password{Enter}")
Start-Sleep -m 2000
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("$accept?{Enter}")
Start-Sleep -m 2000
```